# Torque with 2D center of mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, torque, moment-of-inertia

> A cube of mass M rests tilted against the wall as shown (see below). There is no friction between the wall and the cube, but the friction between the cube and the floor is just sufficient to keep the cube from slipping. When $0\lt\theta\lt 45^\circ$ find the minimum coefficient of friction $\mu_{min}$ as a function of $\theta$

[image: picture showing problem]

**What I've tried**

So, we have two points of contant with the wall. The point of contant between the vertical wall and the cube results in an unknown force $N_1$. You then have three forces on the point of contant between the cube and the 'ground'. $N_2$ is the standard normal force. $\mu N_2$ would be a force parallel to the ground going towards the inner wall to oppose any action to move the cube and $F_2$ is the force parallel to the ground going away from the wall. From here force resolution gets us:

$$\sum F_x = N_2 + F_1 -\mu N2 = 0$$
$$\sum F_y = N_1 - mg(?)$$
$$\sum M_b = ??$$

**why im lost**

So for the $F_y$ force my thinking is that because all of the weight of the cube will be pressing down at that one point we can get the $mg$ term. If not it will need to have a value of $\frac{mgl}{\sqrt{2}}cos(\theta+45)$.

For the moment term I made an assumption that we could consider this box 1d and have the mass along the line so we get $M_b=0=\frac{mgl}{2}cos(\theta)-lN_1 sin(\theta)$. This did not work.

I am thinking I need the CM to be at the center of the cube, in which case I have the mg term as mentioned but I am not sure how to find the $M_b$ term in this case.

**additional stuff**

This problem comes from the problem set for feynman and in the lecture for this he mentions classical field theory. I was also wondering if this problem could be solved using CFT and if it would be a worthwhile exercise to do so. Also, is it possible to solve this using virutal work? And how would I go about doing that? Looking for as many ways to solve this as possible to make sure I can do this later.

Comment: If the sum of the forces is zero (static condition), then the point about which torques are balanced _does not matter_. So draw a free body diagram and balance the forces and torques by replacing each contact with a normal force and a corresponding friction (if applicable).

Comment: @ja72 I think I did that to get the $M_b=\frac{mgl}{2}...$ term. This is centered at the bottom contact point. If I miss understand, sorry.

Comment: To understand what ja72 posted, torque is the vector product of force with perpendicular distance vector from the line of the force to the center of mass. Any displacement of the center of mass results in change in torque of each force. You'll find that the vector sum of the change in torque is zero.

Comment: @KooZhengqun Sorry, I do not really follow.

Comment: Pick whatever point makes the torque calculations simpler.

Comment: A little late, but my earlier comment was referring to ja72's "If the sum of the forces is zero (static condition), then the point about which torques are balanced _does not matter_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A free body diagram is your friend.

[image: FBD]

Now to balance the forces/moments:

$$ \begin{align}
  N_1 - F_2 & = 0 & \mbox{sum of forces in the x-direction}\\
  N_2 - m g & = 0 & \mbox{sum of forces in the y-direction}\\
  N_2 (a \cos \theta) - N_1 (a \sin \theta)-m g ( \frac{a}{2} ( \cos\theta + \sin \theta)) & =0 &\mbox{sum of torques about the origin}
  \end{align} $$

Theese three equations have to be solved for the three unknown forces, $N_1$, $N_2$ and $F_2$.

The minimum coefficient of friction has to be at least equal to $\mu = \frac{F_2}{N_2}$ for each angle.

I will let you work out the details, but the larger the angle $\theta$ the less the friction needs to be. At $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ friction can be 0 as the contact is directly under the center of mass.

Comment: Thanks! but could you explain a little more how you found the terms for the torques? I can see how, if you are picking the origin as the O in the diagram, you get the first two but the last term is still alluding me.

Comment: Start from the origin and go to the center of mass via the contact point. In the _x_-direction this is $$ a\cos \theta - \frac{a}{2} \cos\theta + \frac{a}{2} \sin\theta = \frac{a}{2} ( \cos\theta+\sin\theta)$$

Comment: Thank you, I was just able to confirm that your solution results in the correct answer. I am in the process of getting this it work with the point being the $N_2$,$F_2$ point but not sure how much time I will have in the next couple of days. Do you know if it is possible to do this using virtual work and how to do that?

Comment: @WilliamDaFoe sorry, I don't.